# Explain how this integral is derived by switching to polar coordinates.

Tags: calculus, integration, polar-coordinates

I had a look at the following post in the physics stack exchange about the coulomb field

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7462/fourier-transform-of-the-coulomb-potential?newreg=edecf6cd6c9a404ba842fd7dfb093be8

In Pablo's answer he has the integral $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^3 } \frac{1}{(2 \pi )^3 } \frac{e^{i k \cdot r } }{k^2+a^2} d^3k$$

Which after switching to polar coordinates it becomes $$\frac{1}{(2 \pi )^3 } \int_0^{\infty } \frac{k^2}{k^2+a^2} dk \int_0^{2 \pi } d \phi \int_{-\pi /2 }^{\pi /2} \cos \theta e^{ikr \sin \theta } d \theta $$

However I can't understand how this was derived, since if $k=(k_1,k_2,k_3)$ and $r=((r_1,r_2,r_3)$ spherical coordinates are $$k_1 =\rho \cos \theta \sin \phi $$
$$k_2=\rho \sin \theta \sin \phi $$
$$k_3=\rho \cos \phi $$
so $$e^{ik \cdot r}$$ would become $$e^{i ( \rho \cos \theta \sin \phi r_1+\rho \sin \theta \sin \phi r_2 +\rho \cos \phi r_3 )} $$
I can't see how this resembles the given result, can you explain how is this derived?

Comment: Just a note for the hasty reader  - the $\phi$ of polar coordinates in physics is the $\theta$ of polar coordinates in mathematics....

Comment: Your formula for spherical coordinates is incorrect; you are using mathematicians' coordinates, except that $k_3$ is incorrect, but the integration formula is using physicists' coordinates, switched to measure $\theta$ from the $xy$-plane rather than from the $z$-axis. What a mess!

Comment: Adding to Ted's comment, and now Mark's answer below: First of all, the initial integral is rotationally invariant - it only depends on the magnitude $r$ of $\vec r$. So you can assume that $\vec r$ lies on the $z$ axis.  I think that is what Pablo meant to write - i.e., that he has a typo - when he wrote right before his calculation, "If we use polar coordinates with $\vec k$  in the z-axis we have ..." After all, he is integrating out/over $\vec k$. ...

Comment: ... Secondly: If $\theta$ is the angle above/from the $x-y$ plane [which is not how you seem to be taking it, but how Pablo seems to be], we certainly have that $k_3= k \sin\theta$, and $\vec r \cdot \vec k = rk \sin\theta$.

Comment: @guin_go Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. –

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(\vec r)$ be given by that integral

$$f(\vec r)=\frac1{(2\pi)^3}\int_{\mathbb{R^3}}\frac{e^{i\vec k\cdot\vec r}}{k^2+a^2}\,d^3\vec k$$

With a fixed $\vec r$, we apply a rotational transformation in $\vec k$-space (i.e., $\vec k\mapsto \vec k'$) to align $k'_z$ with $\vec r$.

Note that $k^2=k'^2$ and $\vec k\cdot \vec r=k'r\cos(\theta')$.  Then, inasmuch as the Jacobian of a rotational transformation is equal to $1$, we assert that

$$\begin{align}
f(\vec r)&=\frac1{(2\pi)^3}\int_{\mathbb{R^3}}\frac{e^{i\vec k\cdot\vec r}}{k^2+a^2}\,d^3\vec k\\\\
&=\frac1{(2\pi)^3}\int_{\mathbb{R^3}}\frac{e^{ik'r\cos(\theta')}}{k'^2+a^2}\,d^3\vec k'\\\\
&=\frac1{(2\pi)^3}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi \int_0^\infty \int_{\mathbb{R^3}}\frac{e^{ik'r\cos(\theta')}}{k'^2+a^2}\,k'^2 \sin(\theta')\,dk'\,d\theta'\,d\phi'
\end{align}$$

Can you finish now?

Comment: @guin_go Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: @guin_go And feel free to up vote and accept an answer as you see fit. ;-)